# Cocoa error 134030 when saving core data after database migration

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

In the next version of my app I made a few changes to my core data model.  I made them on a new version of the model.  The changes are simple table and row additions.  I have my persistence store configured to automatically update the tables with `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption`.  This is the 6th update to my Core Data model so it has worked in the past.  When the app updates from the database from the pervious version I get the following error on the first time I try to save the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

```
2014-06-05 06:13:31.944 Topo Maps[4862:60b] Unresolved error The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134030.)
```

I have looked at a lot of posts and comments about error 134030 and they all seem to be around not being able to delete an object or around not being able to update an object that was never inserted.  I am pretty sure neither of those are happening in my app.  When the app first starts up I set a string value on a core data object, then save the managed context, and that is when I get this error.

In the past when I had issues with getting the persistence store to upgrade I would get errors when trying to initialize a persistence store with my managed object model.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out what is going wrong.  I feel like an idiot.  I wasn't printing out all of the data in the NSError.  It turns out that it was from updating an object that was never inserted.  My app saves a URI for the last used object and it was that URI that was causing the problems.  So it was actually not a database migration issue.  It was an issue with how the new version of my app handled the URI in settings.